# Material Design Non-Simple Activity Transition Animations

Tags: android, material-design, android-transitions

I've looked at the ActivitySceneTransitionBasic example in the samples of the Android SDK, which does a very simple transition from a GridView item click into a Detail Activity for the item that was clicked. This example is much too simple. I'd like to do something more complex, like at 21s in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=um1S2u022HA) video. I want the item clicked to become the header in a CollapsingToolbarLayout like the video shows, and I want the same grow animation shown, as it implements what's in the [guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigational-transitions.html) (elevation and expansion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should take a look at Topeka .
http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/06/more-material-design-with-topeka-for_16.html

Available at GitHub:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-topeka